# PIVX fork CryptoDezire Coin SendRawTransaction not working

Tags: bitcoin, rpc, forks

A CDZC coin basically fork of PIVX . I am trying to send coin via rpc calls. Successfuly created RawTxn, SignRawTxn but unable to SendRawTxn.

```
    `await rpc.listunspent().then(async r  => {
         await rpc.createRawTransaction(r.result{'DA3agGab9SxNptHygVkQfyNjBW4YR3ujXm':0.1}).then(async tx  => {
    await rpc.signrawtransaction(String(tx.result),r.result).then(async signtx  => {await rpc.sendRawTransaction(Object.values(signtx.result)[0]).then(async send  => {   console.log("send:",send) }) .catch(err => console.log(err))
                 });
       });      

});
```

[image: SignRawTxn successful response]

[image: Final response when SendRaw called]

Comment: Make Sure you had unlocked the account first and then sending raw transaction through that account.

Comment: @MaheshRajput first i unlock the wallet using my passphrase then i import private key into wallet, then after unspent and other stuff